# Managed Package Install takes too long to show Config page

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, isv, postinstall

As [Post Install Scripts are too limited for my purpose](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/263668/256) I added a custom Config page to my Managed Package because it displays nicely after the installation is done.

The problem is that the installation now is taking longer and switches into this asynchronous mode where the user is told that he is going to be notified by email when the installation is done.

In such cases, no Config page is shown. I know that the user can load it via Setup > Installed Packages but that's not the same.

So my question is:

1. Why do some installations run instant and display the Config pages as part of the installations and others don't?
2. Is there anything I can do to guarantee that it will be displayed?

Comment: Some orgs just take a long time to deploy anything. Especially those with large packages like CPQ of FinancialForce. Is there anything you can do? Short answer is no. One thing we have done is we wrote a custom package installation manager where the install happens from our site. Using the REST API you can install async, check the status using the returned ID and when it is done can navigate the user to the setup page in their org. This path has its own drawbacks though...